# taylor series approximation of e function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

in the equation $$e^{y(x)}=1+2x-\frac{y(x)}{1-x}$$ $y(0)=0$ because using the taylor series and by comparing the coefficients we obtain $$1+y(0)=1-y(0)$$But why is using the taylor series allowed. Actually we do not know that $y(0)<<1$ which is a condition for using the taylor series to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an equation in real numbers, you don't need Taylor series to show that $y(0)=0$. If you substitute $x=0$ into your equation and let $z=y(0)$ we get

$$e^z=1-z$$

This has the unique real solution $z=0$. This is unique since the function on the left hand side is increasing while the one on the right is decreasing.

Comment: How did you find that real solution? By guessing?

Comment: @phth: Yes, by guessing, but the guess was completely obvious. When I guess I almost always try zero and one first.